# data driven put with different formats challenge

Tags: sas, format, datastep

I wanted to come here with this challenge I'm facing in these days.

Basically for each record, a different format should be used in a put statement, and it is defined in the data in theirselves.

The challenge is not to split the datasteps and gaining the wanted result within the datastep, so avoid obvious %do loops and similar :)

```
proc format;
    value $a 'FRS'='FIRST';
    value $b 'SCN'='SECOND';
run;
data a;
    length var $3 res $10 fmt $5;
    var='FRS'; fmt='$a.'; res=''; output;
    var='SCN'; fmt='$b.'; res=''; output;
run;
data b;
    set a;

    *your code goes here, the result should go into res variable;
    *and should be the "putted" value of var using fmt as format.;
    *an obviously non working version can be found here below;

    res=put(var,fmt);
run;
```

Here below what it looks like, res is the expected result:

```
VAR  FMT  RES
---------------
"FRS" $a. =put("FRS",$a.)="FIRST"
"SCN" $b. =put("SCN",$b.)="SECOND"
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure I understand the question, but it looks like you just want to use the `PUTC()` function.  If your variable was numeric you would use the `PUTN()` function instead.

```
res=putc(var,fmt);
```

Comment: unfortunately you can't use a variable as format :(

Comment: in the PUT function that is correct but @tom has shown you PUTC.

Comment: @stat You can definitely use a variable to contain the format specification with `PUTC` and `PUTN` function. That is one of the main differences between them and the `PUT` function.